# Fatal Error, using Import/ Export tool

Tags: php, out-of-memory, phpexcel

I am getting this error when exporting the file.

> Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 377487360) (tried to allocate 71 bytes) in
>       /home/*/public_html/system/PHPExcel/Classes/PHPExcel/CachedObjectStorage/CacheBase.php
>       on line 173**

And on line 173 the code is

```
public function getCellList() {
   return array_keys($this->_cellCache);
}
```

Please help, thanks in advance.

This are value is my **php.ini**

```
magic_quotes_gpc = Off;
register_globals = Off;
default_charset = UTF-8;
memory_limit = 1024M;
max_execution_time = 36000;
upload_max_filesize = 1999M;
safe_mode = Off;
mysql.connect_timeout = 200;
session.use_cookies = On;
session.use_trans_sid = Off;
session.gc_maxlifetime = 172800;
allow_url_fopen = on;
;display_errors = 1;
;error_reporting = E_ALL;
```

But still I am getting the error.

Comment: So what cell caching mechanism are you using? or are you just assuming that PHPExcel can store unlimited data in memory?

Comment: I am new to opencart, so don't know much.
Well i am having only 300 products in 50 categories, still i am getting this error.
Please lemme know the step by step procedure.

Comment: I wrote the underlying PHPExcel library, but I've no idea who wrote the import/export tool you're using, or how they implemented it

Comment: this is the tool i am using (http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=17)
I guess now you would be able to help me, waiting for your reply.

Comment: No, but I'd recommend that you either increase your PHP memory limits, or contact the author of the tool.... he does warn about the high memory usage; perhaps the tool gives you the option to enable PHPExcel cell caching to reduce the memory footprint

Comment: @MarkBaker Please look at the values of php.ini
The memory limit is enough, still no solution.

Comment: `377487360` bytes of memory mentioned in the error message doesn't match the `1024M` in your php.ini - have you changed the correct php.ini file?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted in PhpExcel](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19476176/allowed-memory-size-of-134217728-bytes-exhausted-in-phpexcel)

Answer (score 0):

**You may needs to increase Memory Limit**

```
memory_limit = 2048M;
```

It may work ! (Not mandatory 2048)

Comment: Rise the memory limit is not a solution at all for the production environment.